# Is it good idea to store operational data in memcached?

Tags: c++, database, memcached, scalability

I write data processor on cpp, which should process a lot of requests and do a lot of calculations, requests are connected with each other. Now I think about easy horizontal scalability.

Is it a good idea to use memcached with replication (an instance on every processor) to store operational data? Such every processor instance could process every requests in an equal time.

How fast and stable is memcached replication?

Answer (score 5):

very fast, one major potential shortcoming of memcached is that it is not persistent.  While a common design consideration when using a cache layer is that “data in cache may go away at any point”, this can result in painful warmup time and/or costly cache stampedes.

Comment: What would you suggest for my task?

Answer (score 0):

I would check out Couchbase.  http://www.couchbase.com/  It stores the cached data in RAM, but also flushes it out to disk periodically so if a machine gets restarted, the data is still there.

It's very easy to add nodes on the fly as well.

Just for fun you could also check out Riak: http://basho.com/riak/. Very easy to add nodes as your cache needs grow and very easy to get up and running.  Also focused on key/value storage, which is good for caching objects.